# calculating probability from long series data in python pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, probability

I have a  data ranging from 19 to 49. How can I calculate the probability of the data occurred in between 25 to 40?

```html
46.58762816
30.50477684
27.4195249
47.98157313
44.55425608
30.21066503
34.27381019
48.19934524
46.82233375
46.05077036
42.63647302
40.11270346
48.04909583
24.18660332
24.47549276
44.45442651
19.24542913
37.44141763
28.41079638
21.69325455
31.32887617
26.26988582
18.19898804
19.01329026
28.33846808
```

Comment: Do you simply want to count the values falling between 25 and 40 and divide this count by the total number of values?

Comment: yes i think it will also works @ ajcr

Comment: Is this just a sample of your data or the whole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest you can do is to use the % of values that fall between 25 and 40.

If `s` is your `pandas.Series` you gave us:

```
In [1]: s.head()
Out[1]:
0    46.587628
1    30.504777
2    27.419525
3    47.981573
4    44.554256
Name: 0, dtype: float64

In [2]: # calculate number of values between 25 and 40 and divide by total count
s.between(25,40).sum()/float(s.count())
Out[2]: 0.3599
```

Otherwise it would require trying to find what distribution your data might be following (from the data you gave, which might be just a small sample of your data, it doesn't appear to be following any distribution I know...), testing if it actually follows the distribution you think it follows (using Kolmogorov-Smirnov test or another like it), then you can use that distribution to calculate the probability etc.

Comment: thank you so much now i got it and its working thankz alot :)